# Method call after garbage collection is finished

Tags: python, garbage-collection, destructor, reference-counting

I have a class "Foo" where the objects are registered in an object called FooManager. After the scope of a function is left the Foo objects can only be deleted if I know ALL the Foos which are "tagged for deletion".

```
class FooManager:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.deletion_list = []
    
    def delete_tagged_foos(self):
        #Deletion process
        pass

class Foo:

    def __init__(self, FooManager):
        self.FooManager = FooManager

    def __del__(self):
        self.FooManager.deletion_list.append(self)

        if garbage_collection_finished():
            self.FooManager.delete_tagged_foos()


def foo_processing(manager):
    foo1 = Foo(manager)
    foo2 = Foo(manager)
    foo3 = Foo(manager)
    
    # Tag foo2 and foo3 for deletion (but not foo1)
    # and perform deletion process once every foo is tagged
    return foo1


manager = FooManager()

foo1 = foo_processing(manager)
```

How can I acquire the boolean garbage_collection_finished()?

Comment: Why not define the \_\_del\_\_() method in the FooManager class directly.  Python already does the work of keeping the FooManager instance alive as long as there are instances of Foo referring to it.

Comment: I don't see how this solves my problem? In this example the destructor of FooManager would never be called

Comment: What does `delete_tagged_foos` do? Generally, you don't need to do any garbage collection yourself. When an object's reference count goes to zero, it's memory is reclaimed. Garbage collection proper is only needed to handle reference cycles, where two (or more) objects are only reachable from each other.

Comment: I need to solve this problem in a context of quantum information. The specifics here are mathematically complex and irrelevant. My concern is not memory overflow but providing a convenient implementation that automates tedious tasks that would be performed at this point of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about keeping track of foo instances in the FooManager and using it as a decorator on functions that create temporary foo instances:

```
import sys

class FooManager:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.foos = []

    def registerFoo(self,foo):
        foo.FooManager = self
        self.foos.append(foo)
        print("+1")

    def cleanFoos(self,func):
        def callFunc(*args,**kwargs):
            result = func(*args,**kwargs)
            # 3 refs = self.foos, foo in comprehension, getrefcount param
            orphanFoos = [foo for foo in self.foos if sys.getrefcount(foo)<=3]
            # process orphans as needed
            # leave them in self.foos if they are not to be deleted
            self.foos  = [foo for foo in self.foos if foo not in orphanFoos]
            # ...
            print("foo count:",len(self.foos))
            return result 
        return callFunc
        
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, FooManager):
        FooManager.registerFoo(self)

    def __del__(self): print("deleted")
```

usage:

```
manager = FooManager()

@manager.cleanFoos
def foo_processing(manager):
    foo1 = Foo(manager)
    foo2 = Foo(manager)
    foo3 = Foo(manager)
    
    # Tag foo2 and foo3 for deletion (but not foo1)
    # and perform deletion process once every foo is tagged
    return foo1

foo1 = foo_processing(manager)
```

output:

```
+1
+1
+1
foo count: 1
deleted
deleted
```

Comment: Using a decorator is an amazing idea! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call the method yourself when the function returns:

```py
foo1 = foo_processing(manager)
manager.delete_tagged_foos()
```

At the point of calling `delete_tagged_foos()`, both `foo2` and `foo3` have re-registered themselves with the manager, and so won't be deleted again.

Comment: That would result in an extra line of code after every function which processes foos and non-experienced users might forget calling it. I'd prefer to avoid that.

Comment: There is no way of doing this in python, other than introducing something else to take account of having just 'deleted' some instances.